# Javascript Number() interface is returning wrong number

Tags: typescript, type-conversion

I'm using `Number()` to convert an input into number and it is returning the wrong number.

Couldn't find a reason for this:

```
const aux = Number("3721250857372431234");

console.log(aux)
```

it will print `3721250857372431400` instead of `3721250857372431234`

https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAAhGMHsDsGcBcQEMCuAPEBeEA5FBbAIwFMAnACgCIBmAdgCYBGegVgAYAOF2u+gFmrNqfSgEoA3MFAQYsSABtiAOnmQA5uXgBPAA7FIAM3Ko0o0dKhwFy1RpOigA

Comment: That number is larger than can be accurately represented by the Number type. If you need integers that large you may need to use [BigInts](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt)

Comment: This has almost nothing to do with TypeScript aside from being the language the problem was found in. Mind editing to change it to JavaScript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your number is bigger than the [maximum safe integer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_SAFE_INTEGER) and therefore the precision cannot be guaranteed.